# Insert gives me an empty list? What is going on here?

Tags: python, list

```
>>> numlist = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
>>> numlist = numlist.insert(0, '-1')
>>> numlist
>>> print numlist
None
>>>
```

I don't get it - I am trying to append to the first position of the list, and it is giving me a NoneType?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`list.insert` modifies the list in-place and returns `None`. Use it like this instead:

```
>>> numlist = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
>>> numlist.insert(0, '-1')
>>> numlist
['-1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Also, is there any particular reason you are using quoted numbers?

Answer (score 6):

`list.insert` returns `None`, not a list.

Answer (score 2):

Try `numlist.insert(0, '-1')` without the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
numlist.insert(0, '-1')
```

list.insert will return a None